# Existence of extension of linear map and existence of subspace complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Great answer by Asaf Karagila to my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713561/existence-of-vector-space-complement-and-axiom-of-choice) leads me to further questions.

Let say we deal with vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}.$ Here are three sentences:

1. For every $V$ and its subspace $E\subset V$ there is a subspace $F\subset V$ such that $V=E\oplus F.$
2. For every $V,W,$ subspace $E\subset V$ and linear map $f:E\to W$ there is a linear map $F:V\to W$ such that $F|_E=f.$
3. For every $V,$ subspace $E\subset V$ and linear map $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ there is a linear map $F:V\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $F|_E=f.$

Obviously (1)->(2)->(3). How about the converse? **Do (3)->(2) and (2)->(1)?**

From answer to my previous question we know that AC<->(1). For me, (3) looks like unnormed version of Hahn-Banach theorem. But as we read on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Relation_to_axiom_of_choice), H-B does not imply (3).

Comment: I'd begin by looking into Morillon's paper mentioned in [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573297/existence-of-hamel-basis-choice-and-regularity/1573309#1573309), and by reading [this answer of Martin](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623210/hahn-banach-theorem-for-separable-spaces-without-zorns-lemma/1631556#1631556). In short, we know some things about linear functionals in ZF, but not a whole lot of things. Most likely neither implication is reversible, but I think if any of them is known, it might only be that (3) does not imply (1). But I don't know.