# Does "every normed vector space has a basis" imply choice

Tags: vector-spaces, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, hamel-basis

It is known that if every vector space has a basis, then the axiom of choice holds. Is the weaker claim that every normed space (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) has a basis enough to prove $AC$?

I'm also interested in the stronger assumption the this is true for "normed" vector fields over arbitrary ordered fields, or the same idea with some other generalization of a norm I may not know about.

Comment: It is an open problem, as far as I know. Nothing much is known about this direction, and you may check [my previous question and Asaf's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1573297/53976) to see some of it.

Comment: @HanulJeon   it seems that link is about what can be proved in ZF - regularity.  So is it relevant here?

Comment: Another relevant question that points towards it being open is [discussed here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/441393/113405)

Comment: @GEdgar Not entirely irrelevant. Blass' proof of AC from the existence of bases substantially uses Regularity, and we do not know whether the implication holds without it. Since Blass' proof is the only currently known proof for the implication, examining his proof from a different perspective can be a way to work on this problem. But I acknowledge what Holo linked is more relevant, though.

Comment: Related: [Over ZF, does "every Hilbert space have a basis" imply AC?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/951846)